# What is the term for an essay that analyzes other essays?

Tags: single-word-requests

Are there terms which distinguish between (a) an essay that focuses on presenting and analyzing the *information* presented in various sources (e.g. topic: "Food Sources of Ants") and (b) an essay that focuses instead on analyzing the *form* of those essays (e.g. topic: "A Comparison of the Text Structure of Articles on Ant Food Sources")?

The later has no concern with addressing the *information* or *facts* or even *arguments* given in the initial sources, but instead just focuses on examining the choices the authors made in how they approached the writing and presentation of the information.

Sample sentences where these terms could appear:

(a)

> Frank wrote an essay where he described the food sources of ants using
>   three different sources he found on-line.

(b)

> Kyle wrote an essay where he described how the authors of each source
>   used different text structures, and showed how each author's choice
>   impacted the readability of the texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first type of essay (a) that you mention, "an essay that focuses on presenting and analyzing the information presented in various sources", is squarely concerned with an analysis of the facts, and so is an example of an expository essay, there's a reasonable definition provided by time4writing.com.

[Expository essay](https://www.time4writing.com/writing-resources/types-of-essays/):

> The expository essay is an informative piece of writing that presents a balanced analysis of a
>   topic. In an expository essay, the writer explains or defines a topic,
>   using facts, statistics, and examples.

(b)
An essay which compares two or more other pieces of writing, is termed a

[Comparative essay](http://www.uc.utoronto.ca/comparative-essay):

> A comparative essay asks that you compare at least two (possibly more)
>   items. These items will differ depending on the assignment. You might
>   be asked to compare
>
> ...
>   texts (e.g. Shakespeare’s Hamlet and Macbeth)

-University of Toronto.

Comment: *Essay* is usually used for something [expressing an opinion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essay); something giving scientific results or performing analysis would be a *paper*, *article*, *report*, *study*, etc.

Comment: @StuartF, this is true when these words are used for published works, but in educational settings, *essay* is often used for anything longer than a couple of sentences that the students are required to produce.